# Stop DataGrid from automatically resizing after filtering rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm implementing a datagrid with row filter, something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering

My rows and columns are automatically generated by a result I get from the database.

The issue I am seeing is, when I perform a filter, my datagrid automatically resize which is kind of annoying. I would rather see the filtered out rows just disappear but remain the height of the datagrid.

I have set my datagrid's max height to 150, but the moment I perform filtering, it will resize itself to a shorter height.

How can I stop the auto-resizing from happening? For example, if the datagrid is loaded with 5 rows which consumes 150px in height, then I filter it to show 2 rows, I would still like my datagrid to be 150px in height.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `Height` property. The `MaxHeight` only limit your datagrid not grow taller than that value, but not limit your datagrid being shorter.

```
<DataGrid Name="yourDataGrid" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

> I do not want to initialize a fixed height, but basically I just want
>   to retain the height. Even though I set MaxHeight=150, let's say I
>   have 3 rows which takes up height 100px, when I filter, I would like
>   to retain the height of 100px.

In this case

```
yourDataGrid.Height= yourDataGrid.ActualHeight;
// Start Filter
// ...
// ClearFilter: clear the fixed height
yourDataGrid.Height = double.NaN;
```

Comment: I do not want to initialize a fixed height, but basically I just want to retain the height. Even though I set MaxHeight=150, let's say I have 3 rows which takes up height 100px, when I filter, I would like to retain the height of 100px.

Comment: I was looking if there's a property I could set to achieve what I want, I guess this is a way to go :)

Btw, do I really need to set the Height back to NaN?

Comment: @DhinneshJeevan yes, if not when number of rows change your grid height don't follow these changes

Comment: that's the purpose, my datagrid height should not change when number of rows change. It should be fixed since the beginning according to the number of rows loaded. So, setting it back to NaN will not work. I've tried it and it doesn't work, ignoring the NaN works for me.

Comment: @DhinneshJeevan it is true for your case, but from my apps I ussually clear the fixed height after I clear the filter. For example when you insert new row to the grid, if you don't clear this value, gid will not grow higher

Comment: For your case, you just need to set to NaN and that's it right? Do you still need to set Height=ActualHeight and then to NaN?

Comment: You only set to `NaN` after you fully clear your filter. And before you start new filter, you set `Height=ActualHeight` again.